# Skype chat history and web browsing history

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, skype, history

In an office work place, can a network admin have access to my Skype chat history and web browsing history without logging in to my pc since all pc's are connected with the same network?

Comment: This entirely depends on the configuration of the network itself.  ALL web browsing history can be logged.  Your chat history is stored both on your computer and in the cloud.  A properly configured network likely means a domain administrator has access to all files on your work computer.

Comment: @Ramhound tnx but without logging in to my pc from server side the admin can check what are the sites i accessed and all right ?

Comment: As @Ramhound said it depends on the configuration, but it is always the best policy to assume so.

Comment: @mazraara - They can simply log into your computer they have physical access to your machine. Unless there is a domain server there likely isn't a "server".  A domain server doesn't keep track of your traffic there is specialized hardware for that.

Comment: Note that some companies also install a keylogger, which means that they have a record of everything you've done to interact with the machine, and can easily replay things to see what you did. End-to-end HTTPS can protect you *to an extent*, but you'd need to manually verify the certificate chain for a site that is purportedly secure, and make sure that the content that gets downloaded by your browser isn't being passed to another server after it's downloaded. In short, the company owns the network and the PCs, so it can do a lot of nasty things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This entirely depends on the configuration of the network itself. ALL web browsing history can be logged. Your chat history is stored both on your computer and in the cloud. A properly configured network likely means a domain administrator has access to all files on your work computer